# React Boilerplate: Dumb components re-render when the data in

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect, react-boilerplate

I have a used **react-boilerplate** to setup the base for my project. Consider I have a container and 2 components(dumb components) like below,

```
App
  - HomePage(Connected component with sidebarData and detailedData)
     - SideBar(data=sidebarData)
     - DetailedView(data=detailedData)
State
  {
    "sidebarData": makeSelectorSideBarData(), // reselect selector
    "detailedData": makeSelectorDetailedViewData(), // reselect selector
  }
```

It's clear that the child components are depends on individual data. But when my `detailedData` changes, it re-renders the `SideBar` component also.

Is there anyway to avoid this using redux/reselect and without implementing `shouldComponentUpdate()` ?

Comment: It might be worth looking into [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a component to re-render until the props given to it change, you can use [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). Just make sure you know shallow prop and state comparisons will suffice for your use case:

> `PureComponent`’s `shouldComponentUpdate()` only shallowly compares the
>   objects. If these contain complex data structures, it may produce
>   false-negatives for deeper differences

Comment: Yeah, It worked. But is there any other way without using `PureCompoents` ?

Comment: @KamalakannanJ - you can use https://github.com/NoamELB/shouldComponentUpdate-Children

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PureComponent alternative - **shouldComponentUpdate-Children** - https://github.com/NoamELB/shouldComponentUpdate-Children

```
import {shallowEqual} from 'shouldcomponentupdate-children';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return shallowEqual(this.props, nextProps, this.state, nextState);
    }
}
export default MyComponent;
```

The github link also includes a live codepen example.